# No Backend Icons FLUID Powered TYPO3 - wrong path?

Tags: icons, typo3, backend, fluid, fedext

after my first steps with FLUID POWERED TYPO3.

The latest versions `flux 7.1.2`, `fluidpages 3.1.2`, `fluidcontent 4.1.1`, `fluidcontent_core 1.0.2`, `vhs 2.1.4`

I've got only a small issue ... I don't see my Icons for FLUIDPAGES or FLUX CONTENT ELEMENTS at TYPO3 Backend.

[image: choose fluidpages or add new content element :: no icons availible]

This is the Icon Path for Fluidpages-Images from Screenshot:

```
typo3conf/ext/mvz_neuhann/Resources/Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif
```

I try it with or without baseURL nothing happens. The Icon is visible, when I paste the path into my Browser:
[image: Icon there?]
But my JS-Console says:

```
http://mvz.local/typo3/typo3conf/ext/mvz_neuhann/Resources/Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

Because of the '`typo3/`' after my URL. But why? I'm on a local Server, no File Permissons or sth., Clear Cache, delete typo3temp.

Nothing. I can't see my Icons from my provider Extension via fluidpages or flux. It's the same with my FLUX Icons, the Standard-Icon is availible but how is the path at my flux form?

I've tried:

```
<flux:form id="home05" options="{group: 'xy', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Public/Icons/Content/myicon.gif\')}'}">
// or
<flux:form id="home05" options="{icon: 'typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/myicon.gif', group: 'xy'}">
//
<flux:form id="home05" options="{icon: 'EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/myicon.gif', group: 'xy'}">
```

Comment: What's the value of the TypoScript settings `config.baseURL`, `config.absRefPrefix`, `page.config.baseURL` and `page.config.absRefPrefix` (Assuming your main page object is named `page`)?

Comment: `config.baseURL = http://mvz.local` - no absRefPrefix or realURL set

Comment: What versions of flux, fluidpages, etc. are you using?

Comment: The latest versions `flux 7.1.2`, `fluidpages 3.1.2`, `fluidcontent 4.1.1`, `fluidcontent_core 1.0.2`, `vhs 2.1.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in the backend, Flux creates a relative path to your Icon. To be precise, it creates a relative path to `PATH_site` constant. This means in your iframe, the path is plain wrong. This is a common issue with backend images. There's a few ways to solve this:

1. Create a custom, absolute uri with `f:uri.resource` and `f:uri.image` (absolute paths)

   - Example with proper escaping would be

   `<flux:form id="fluidpage" options="{icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/myImage.gif\')}'}">`
2. prefix your path with a slash if it's a custom Icon so the path will start at your root
3. There should also be automatic icon discovery which will find an icon `Resources/Public/Icons/Standard.(png|gif)` for your page Template `Standard.html`

If you have further issues, please refer to our bugtracker on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for your help (again). But there must be sth. wrong ... I try it like this: `<flux:form id="fluidpage" options="{icon: '{f:uri.image(path: \'Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif\')'}">` and my output is like this: `<img src="{f:uri.image(path: 'Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif')" alt="Homepage">`

Comment: This means you got an error in your fluid syntax, not more, not less. :) in-line VHs are tricky re escaping. Did you try the easiest solution (Number 3 in my List)?

Comment: The inline notation won't be rendered correct?! `{icon: '{f:uri.image(path: \'EXT:mvz_neuhann/Resources/Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif\')'}` should be `typo3conf/ext/mvz_neuhann/Resources/Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif`  -  I try to use the standard icon, but now it's a bit confused

Comment: Standard Icon Pt. 3 works: `<flux:form id="fluidpage" options="{icon:'../typo3conf/ext/flux/Resources/Public/Icons/Plugin.png'}">`

Comment: Wow ...  finally: `<flux:form id="fluidpage" options="{icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/myImage.gif\')}'}">` and it works. Thanks Cedric ...  and I also need a night over it ...

Comment: Great, I just edited my answer so others will find it easier. Thx! :)