# How do I know which file system apache can not access on windows?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I have a Typo3 application which is running on Apache2 on Windows 10 (as a part of XAMPP).
In apache error log I see this:

```
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
...
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
```

with no information about which file can not be opened. The string is in german and stands for "The System can not find specified path.". I gave up trying to find the place in PHP code which causes the problem and the string is not coming from PHP or Typo3. It seem to come from Apache or Windows.

I also tried raising the Apache error_log level to `debug`, but that didn't help as well.

So the question is: how do I find out which path on filesystem Apache tries to access?

**UPDATE:** php error log is empty and it is enabled in php.ini - other errors do arrive there.

**UPDATE2:** looks like I found the problem - it was to do with icons handling for fluid content element templates. Three of my templates had icons assigned to them, and icon paths are suffixed with '[0]' for some reason by my version of Typo3. Then Typo3 attempts to call imagemagik with wrong image path as a source. Imagemagik in turn refuses to render image and says that "Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.". [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601412/no-backend-icons-fluid-powered-typo3-wrong-path) helped while investigating. That means my assumption was correct - error is coming from operation system, and I still do not know the answer to my question:

**In which place in Windows I can track back such errors and actually see which paths were/are broken?**

Comment: Look in the `PHP Error log`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, good point, but no - see my update in the question about php-error log

Comment: Check the TYPO3 Docs. It sounds like it is expecting an Apache `Alias` to have been setup for typo3 pointing to another folder not inside the standard site folder structure

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't see how aliases might influence my problem, and I don't have aliases setup anyway.

Comment: You might get more information if you look at the Windows Event Log